# How to load collection view cell from a specific index path?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am working on designing a calendar using a collection view. I am getting the days of week for each month. If for 01-02-207 the day of week start from 3, I need to load the cell from the 3rd position of the collection view. If I get 6 I should load from the 6th position. Can any one help?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let s = CGSize(width: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 7), height: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 7))
    return s
}

//UICollectionViewDatasource methods
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return numDays
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier,for:indexPath) as! collectDayCellCollectionViewCell


    let myString = String(yourArray[indexPath.row])

    cell.day_lbl.text = myString
    cell.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()
    return cell
}

// custom function to generate a random UIColor
func randomColor() -> UIColor{
    let red = CGFloat(drand48())
    let green = CGFloat(drand48())
    let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
    return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a struct to hold all the info you require foreach calendar month.  I don't know where your getting your data from, wether is a query of some API or you have an array somewhere but the below should get you going.  Mind you theres probably better way of going about this.

```
import UIKit

struct MonthStruct {
    var monthSequence: Int // this will help sort the array
    var month : String
    var numberOfDays : Int
    var startIndex : Int  // or startDay if using days
}

class MyClass: UIViewController {

// make an array from the struct items

var monthArray = [MonthStruct]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    for months in year { // year being your data source from query or array????

        // hardcoding values to demonstrate
        monthArray.append(MonthStruct(monthSequence: 1,         // : month[0]   // : month.object.objectForKey.....
                                      month: "Janruary",        // : month[1]
                                      numberOfDays: 31,         // : month[2]
                                      startIndex: 3)            // : month[3]
        )

    }

}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // [0] or other depending on month you want to display
    return monthArray[0].numberOfDays
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier,for:indexPath) as! collectDayCellCollectionViewCell

   // this will just show stuff for cells after Tuesday
    if indexPath.item >= monthArray[0].startIndex {
        cell.day_lbl.text = myString
        cell.backgroundColor = self.randomColor()
    }

    return cell
}


}
```